# How to prepend setting in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I prepend to an SBT setting?

`++=` *appends*. What *prepends*?

(Background: I want to put different resolvers before Typesafe for my Play project.)

Comment: I suspect this might not even be SBT specific but more about Scala syntax in general.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the value to be the given resolver + the old ones, that way the old values all go the back of the search queue.

For build.sbt:

```
resolvers := ("releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2") +: resolvers.value
```

For Build.scala try something like:

```
lazy val root = Project("myproject", file("."))
    .settings(otherSettings: _*)
    .settings(resolvers := ("releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2") +: resolvers.value)
```

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol value" I am using `Build.scala` instead of `build.sbt`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the answer to show a possible build.scala version. In that example I set two sets of settings, but you could roll them into one.

Comment: That does not work in contemporary (SBT 1.x) versions ... For some reason it thinks resolver.value is Seq[Object] when in fact it is Seq[Resolver] UPDATE: use `++` instead.